# Individual user fine grained ACL is it possible in Joomla! 3.x

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, user, acl

I was wondering if it was possible in Joomla! 3.x to have permissions down to individual user level.

Eg:
user A **can see** item X but **not** user B **even if** user B is in the **same group** or have the **same access** level.

or

user A **can do something** on item X but **not** user B **even if** user B is in the **same group** or have the **same access level**.

In essence, I am asking if there is a way to separate ACL down to individual user via some kind of programming in php in Joomla! 3.x

Comment: Please offer more details about your application, how the items are stored, and any programmical steps you've taken. When we better understand your situation, we can offer more specific advice.

Comment: This page appears to be resolved based on your edit of the question -- this is not how Stack Exchange questions are meant to be resolved.  As far as the system knows, this page is unresolved.  Please write an answer that educationally explains what you did and mark your own answer with the green tick if you think it is the best answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without 3rd party extensions, it can't be done in Joomla as long as the 2 users belong to the same group.

But it can be done with 3rd part extensions or some php programming.

Comment: did you manage to make this work? If not, do you know an extension to do this please?

Comment: No one asked me to do this work before :) unfortunately I don't know any extension can do this right now, although I can do it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do that directly. but will need a 3rd party solution. I have some suggestions:

1. you can use a subscription extension and put each user in a
   different subscription plan and mange permission with plans instead
   of groups.
2. you can write an extension that can handle different permissions to assign them to users and a plugin which will do what you entered in this component.
3. and there is a difficult solution , to make a group for each user!! and manage things through normal permissions manager.
4. there is an extension called "Acl manager" do some of what you need.